# Why container stop after succeful registeration runner?

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-command

I want to register  gitlab runner once in  my  docker-compose. yaml. I  touch  the command in  command  section to  register in  non  interactive mode.Why container stop after succeful  register runner?
version: '3.6'

```yaml
volumes:
  portainer_data:

networks:
  mnt_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:
  executor_docker_kaniko:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX}kaniko
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine3.13-v14.8.3
    #restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
       - ./workspace:/home/gitlab-runner
       #- ./executor_docker/config/config.json:/kaniko/.docker/config.json
       #- ./kaniko/ssl:/kaniko/ssl/certs
       #- /srv/gitlab/config/ssl:/kaniko/ssl/certs
       - /srv/gitlab/config/ssl:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
       - ./executor_docker/config/:/etc/gitlab-runner
    #build: 
    #  context: ./executor_docker/build/
    #  dockerfile:  Dockerfile.txt
    command: register --non-interactive --executor "docker" --docker-image gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug --tls-ca-file=/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.blk-astra-v01.crt  --url=https://gitlab.blk-astra-v01/ --registration-token=${PROJECT_REGISTRATION_TOKEN} --description "executor_docker-kaniko" --tag-list "linux"  --run-untagged="true" \
         --maintenance-note "Free-form maintainer notes about this runner" \
         --locked="false" \
         --access-level="not_protected" 
    #команда  ниже регистрирует  раннер где executor= docker, а image =kaniko
    #command:>
    # -run 
    #  - --user=gitlab-runner 
    #  - --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
    extra_hosts:
      - "${GITLAB_SERVER_NAME}:192.168.100.224"
      - "blk-astra-v01:192.168.100.224"
```

docker log:
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=7 revision=16ae0625 version=14.8.3
Running in system-mode.

Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=xW84U-_X
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!

Answer (score 0):

The container exits because the `register` command exits. You probably want to use the `run` command, which is the default command for the image.

You only need to run the `register` command once, which will write the config to the `/etc/gitlab-runner/` directory, which is expected to be mounted when you start the container.

So, assuming you've already successfully written the config, you should be able to just remove the `command:` key from your compose file and the runner should work as expected.